# IE11 issue with Underscore/Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, underscore.js, internet-explorer-11

I am currently debugging a piece of JavaScript. It all works in Chrome but not in IE11. The code uses the Underscore library, although I am unsure if that is where the problem lies. What happens is that in Chrome no errors, in IE it shows "SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number". This is the code:

```
        function getEnumConfig(streams){
        //TODO: handle digital pi points
        var enumBatchRequest = {};
        _.chain(streams)
            .map(function(stream, index){return {Index: index,
                                                 Type: stream.Content.Type,
                                                 EnumUrl: stream.Content.Links.EnumerationSet}})
            .where({Type: "EnumerationValue"})
            .each(function(enumstream){ _.extend(enumBatchRequest,
                                        getEnumRequest(enumstream.EnumUrl, enumstream.Index),
                                        getEnumValuesRequest(enumstream.Index))}) 
            .value();

        return enumBatchRequest;
    };

    function getEnumRequest(enumUrl, index){

        return {['EnumConfig' + index]: {'Method': 'GET', 'Resource': enumUrl}} // Error points to this line...
    }
```

I am by far a great JavaScript programmer so to be honest, I don't have a clue what is going wrong. Anyone able to clarify this to me?

Kind regards,
Hans

Comment: `['EnumConfig' + index]:` this is only supported in ES6.

Comment: In addition to what @Tushar said, try using babel to compile for older browsers.

Comment: I see, is there any sort of ES5 equivalent for this piece of code? Again, I got this code and they told me "to get it to work", first time I see Javascript..

Comment: Thank you Tushar and Jared Smith. I used Babel to convert the code to the ES5 equivalent. It actually works now!